# calculated column Isnumber search

Tags: sharepoint-list

I'm trying to create an if search function so that column B displays a specific "text" when it detects a specific "text" in column A

So in my formula if column A has the word "Assessing" in it, then Column B shows "Internal" and if Column A has "Repairer and supplier" then Column B shows "External".

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Assessing",a2)),"Internal", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Repairer and Supplier",a2)),"External"))

It works great in excel but In SharePoint I get something went wrong error when i save it into a calculated column.

Would appreciate any help I can get

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What result are you getting? Not seeing any issues. Tested in SharePoint Online

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Assessing",ColumnA)),"Internal",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Repairer and Supplier",ColumnA)),"External",""))
```

[image]